# How to add external dependencies in VS Code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I have a Java project, which is an Intellij IDEA project, not a maven or Gradle project,
I want to work with the project in Visual Studio Code now, but I have a problem, I have an external dependency for handling CSV files called Jsefa(Java Simple Exchange Format API).

How can I add this dependency to my Visual Studio Code  Project so that I can build the project in VS Code easily that uses this library??

Can I do this with some modifications in the `settings.json` file? or is there another way??

Comment: Why are you using VS Code to program Java?

Comment: I use Intellij but sometimes I require a lightweight experience, and VS Code provides it.

Comment: how did you open IDEA project in VScode?

Comment: How's your folder structure like when opened in VS Code? No build tools project can add to [referenced libraries](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_manage-dependencies-for-unmanaged-folder). You may try adding `"java.project.referencedLibraries": ["abouslute\\path\\to\\jsefa.jar",],` in `.vscode/settings.json` then reload window. Code then see if you can import package successfully.